# Grails: Prevent cascading association between two domain classes with multiple relationships

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many, cascade

Consider two domain classes; Job and Quote.

A Job has many Quotes but a Job also has an accepted quote. The accepted quote is nullable and should only be set once a particular Quote has been accepted by a user. I have the relationships mapped as follows (simplified for the purpose of illustration).

```
class Job {
    String title
    Quote acceptedQuote   
}

class Quote {
    Job job
    BigDecimal quoteAmount 
}
```

The resultant tables are exactly what I require (at least aesthetically) but the problem arises when I go and save a Quote.
The Quote is saved successfully with a jobId as per the logic in my code but unfortunately the quote's id gets saved in the Job table as the acceptedQuote. Is there anyway to block this cascading association? The code that persists the Quote is fairly basic and looks something like the following;

```
def quoteInstance = new Quote(job: jobInstance, quoteAmount: amount)
if (quoteInstance.save(flush: true)) {
   render view: 'show', model: [quoteInstance: quoteInstance]
   break
}
```

Obviously the jobInstance is passed to the Quote constructor to save an association in the Quote table but I do not know how to prevent the quote Id saving to the job table as the accepted quote.
Maybe the GORM strategy I am using will not satisfy these requirements?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be what you are looking for but I would actually model this a little differently - I would have an accepted flag in the `Quote` domain:

```
class Job {
    String title
    static hasMany = [quotes: Quote]
}

class Quote {
    static belongsTo = [job: Job]
    BigDecimal quoteAmount
    Boolean accepted
}
```

Then your persistence could look like this:

```
jobInstance.addToQuotes(new Quote(quoteAmount: 123.34, accepted: false)) //or true
```

and no worries regarding your original problem.

You could also add a transient and its `getter` to the `Job` class to get the accepted `Quote`

```
class Job {
    String title
    static hasMany = [quotes: Quote]

    static transients = ['acceptedQuote']

    Quote getAcceptedQuote() {
        return Quote.findByJobAndAccepted(this, true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Bingo! Next time I have to type faster. :)

Comment: The coincidence is that I was about the comment the same sentence you did. :) @Kelly added to my pair programmer list. :)

Comment: I would also add a custom validation constraint on Quote that prevents a Job from having more than one accepted Quote

Comment: I'm honestly not trying to save face :-/ but I had actually thought of that but was going for the other solution for performance reasons. But the more I think of it, I don't think there is that much of an advantage nor is it an elegant strategy. I guess I started thinking about it too much. I'll go with this solution. Cheers all.

Answer (score 0):

Grails/GORM has made the associations simpler by following the methodology of convention over configuration and making things more verbose.

What do you think of the below structure of the `domain` classes?

```
class Job {
    String title
    static hasMany = [quotes: Quote]//Job has many Quotes. Note: Accepted Quote is one of them.
}

class Quote {
    BigDecimal quoteAmount
    Boolean isAccepted

    static belongsTo = [job: Job]//Quote always belongs to a Job.
    //When a Job is deleted, quote is also cascade deleted.
}
```

Now if you create your quote like below then everything should work perfectly:

```
def job = new Job(title: "Test Job").save()
//Just adding a quote
def quoteInstance = new Quote(quoteAmount: amount)
job.addToQuotes(quoteInstance)
job.save()

//Now accepting that quote
quoteInstance.isAccepted = true
job.save()
```

Done.

Do we need an `acceptedQuote` reference in Job? No
How to get to the acceptedQuote?

`def acceptedQuote = job.quotes.find{it.isAccepted}`

Comment: I would also add a custom validation constraint on `Quote` that prevents a `Job` from having more than one accepted `Quote`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html) and [belongsTo](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html) association configuration. Take a look at [cascade](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html) to learn more about cascade behaviour configuration.