# How do I properly map a domain that has a one-to-many as well as a many-to-one to another domain?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-2.0.4

Let's say I have the following domain objects:

```
class Family {
    Person primaryContact
    static hasMany = [ members: Person ]
}

class Person {
    static belongsTo = [ family: Family ]
}
```

In other words, a `Family` can have multiple `members`, but only one `Person`, who is also in the `members`, can be the `primaryContact`. `Family` has a bidirectional one-to-many relationship with `Person`, but it also has a unidirectional many-to-one relationship with `Person` as well.

My question is, have I mapped this properly? According to the database tables, the correct columns are created, but the [build-testdata](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin can't build an instance of `Family` because one of the `Person` instances is transient and wasn't saved.

Can someone please help?

Comment: `hasMany` and `belongsTo` should be static.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. It's just an example, so I typed it by hand.

Comment: You can achieve what you want doing something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16472407/2051952) adding a flag in Person to determine if Person is the primary contact instead of adding it to Family. Mark the comments in the domain class.