# Grails / Gorm: Disable implicit association between two domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and have two domain classes,

```
class User {
    Image image
}
class Image {
    User user
}
```

I have a user loaded and create a new image with

```
def image = new Image(user: user)
image.save()
```

GORM now automagically updates the user's `image` to point to the newly saved `Image`.

Is there any way to disable this behavior? The nice folks in #grails advised to use `static mapping = { user cascade: 'none' }` but this didn't help.

([Here is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471962/grails-prevent-cascading-association-between-two-domain-classes-with-multiple-r) but I would like to avoid modelling a relationship with `belongsTo`/`hasOne` and just get rid of this magic.)

Comment: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ian Roberts for the link to the `mappedBy` documentation. I wasn't aware of the "none" magic.

This resolved the issue for me:

```
class Image {
    User user
    static mappedBy = [ user: "none" ] // *** added ***
}
```